# create intent from thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, android-intent

I need to create intent from thread:

```
final Runnable installapps = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        String[] fnames = appsPath.list();
        for (String curfile : fnames) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)),
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};
```

I tried using runOnUiThread but it's still cant be done (app crashed).

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass a reference of an activity to `Intent` constructor.

Comment: Post your log here, there may be many reasons for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it with a handler and StartActivityForResult(). It starts installation Intent, waits for any result (just closing of intent), and executes next one.

`handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);`

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        appcounter++;
        if (appcounter < fnames.length) { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(appsPath + "/" + fnames[appcounter])), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivityForResult(intent, req);  
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      Log.d("CheckStartActivity","onActivityResult and resultCode = "+resultCode);
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   //  appcounter++; 
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the new `Intent` from within an `Activity` class.   Then simply invoke:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this);
```

Comment: edited question. I have a loop, that executes intent one by one. How can I do that from thred? Maybe I havent understood the answer...

Comment: simply put the intent in a loop, however, that isn't a good idea because intents are used to start `Activities` so it doesn't make sense to have a loop start several `Activities` because only 1 can run at a time.

Comment: Perhaps you should better describe what you are really trying to do

Comment: I am making an app that installs apks one by one. That's why I need loop one by one

Comment: Can you provide example of what you said in answer, because I didnt catch

Comment: You cannot install multiple apks automatically like that. The system needs the user approval (the install application activity that is displayed), so your loop, even if it works, wouldn't (couldn't) have the desired effect. It's a matter of security. If you want to install multiple apks, you should do it one by one, checking whichever apks are installed and then asking the user for the subsequent apk. Every time. Sending a bunch or install requests in a row just won't work.